# Does IBM APIConnect work with 3rd party gateways

Tags: ibm-datapower, apiconnect

Does IBM APIConnect work with 3rd party gateways other than IBM Datapower gateway?

Answer (score 2):

No, it is purposely built to run on DataPower only.

Version 5 did run on a Node.js based runtime called Microgateway but that is not supported on the newer 2018 version.